# log4j2 monitorInterval attribute is not working when you initialize property file programmatically

Tags: java, log4j2, talend

I am using log4j2.12.1 api and core jars and initializing log4j2 properties file manually with below code.when i am changing the root logging level to debug or info in properties file it is not reflecting in my logs.I have given monitorInterval=5

```
FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(log4jConfigFile);
java.util.Properties properties =new java.util.Properties();
properties.load(input);
ConfigurationSource source = null;
PropertiesConfiguration source_new = new PropertiesConfigurationBuilder().setConfigurationSource(source).setRootProperties(properties).build();
                 Configurator.initialize(source_new);
```

Please suggest if I am doing anything wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I was loading the file as stream which was getting unknown source location for tracking the configuration file.

*DEBUG Started configuration XmlConfiguration[location=stream (-1 bytes, unknown location)]*

Below code works well for properties file

```
ConfigurationSource source = new  ConfigurationSource(new 
FileInputStream(log4jConfigFile), new java.io.File(log4jConfigFilePath));
                 Configurator.initialize(null,source);
```

For Xml File

```
Configurator.initialize(null,log4jConfigFilePath);
```